# Rails: unable to use a Regex in assert_select block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I want to check each link contained within my navigation against a regex. I've checked this same navigation for various links before using code like this:

```
assert_select "nav.active" do |nav|
  assert_select nav, "a[href=?]", edit_post_path(post), count: 0
end
```

Which works great. I'm unable to do something similar using a regex, as seen in the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select). I've tried using these variations (both of them commented out on purpose):

```
assert_select "nav.active" do |nav|
  #assert_select "a[href=?]", /.+/
  #assert_select nav, "a[href=?]", /foo/, count: 1
end
```

Which fails and outputs this:

```
Minitest::Assertion:  Expected exactly 1 element matching "a[href=/.+/]", found 0..
```

or

```
Minitest::Assertion:  Expected exactly 1 element matching "a[href=/foo/]", found 0..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I came across this question today while looking for a similar answer. I just used this line successfully in my test:

```
assert_select "input:match('value',?)", /Clear search:/, count: 0
```

So the following should work.

```
#assert_select "a[href=?]", /.+/
assert_select "a:match('href',?)", /.+/

#assert_select nav, "a[href=?]", /foo/, count: 1
assert_select "a:match('href',?)", /foo/, count: 1
```

Rails 5 uses Nokogirl's implementation of assert_select. Based on its documentation, I don't think you need a reference to `nav` in the loop. https://github.com/kaspth/rails-dom-testing/blob/master/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb